# Transforming groupedby pandas dataframe (multiple but not all columns) from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, transformation

**The problem:**

I have a dataset with yearly data of different companies. The data is stored in a long format, each year is a row therefore company ids are duplicated.
The data looks like this (however in the original dataframe I have lot more columns).

[image]

I would need to transform the long type format to wide type format, so each company will be shown in one row (no duplication)

This is the result I would like to look like:

[image]

As you can see I would need:

- some columns (like "year") are not needed any more
- some columns (like "sales", "sales_change_in_2_years", "sales_change_over_year") should be transformed from wide format to long format and keeping their names (and adding a number to them)
- some columns (like "ind1" and "ind2") should remain as they are (no transformation from wide to long)

So far I was able to workout a solution which works only on one columns, so it is really not a solution for me.

This is my code:

```
test.groupby("comp_id")['sales_change_1'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: 'sales_{}'.format(x+1))
```

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

After you drop the years:

```
del test['Year']
```

You can manage to group the lines together by adding an extra column with the row "index" for each row belonging to the same company.

```
test['idx'] = test.groupby('Comp_id').cumcount() + 1
```

Then set it as part as the DataFrame index and use `unstack()` to turn it into columns.

```
test = test.set_index(['Comp_id', 'idx']).unstack()
```

At this point, your columns will be a MultiIndex with the created `'idx'` as a second level, so you could already use the DataFrame as it stands referring to columns as `('Sales', 1)`, `('Sales', 2)`, etc.

If you want to flatten your columns, using underscore as the separator, you can do so with:

```
test.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(col, idx) for (col, idx) in test.columns]
```